# Calling requestPermissions twice on custom kernel calls onRequestPermissionsResult before user response

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a project in which I ask for 2 permissions on startup. In debugging, it works as intended until it makes the second call to `requestPermissions`. As soon as it does, the first one fires the `onRequestPermissionsResult` with an empty `grantResults` array.

This worked fine until just today. The only thing I can think of is the updates I have done today. I updated to Android SDK Platform Tools 23.1, and updated my Mac to El Capitan.

Can anyone help me fix whatever is up?

Code follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blank_layout);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasCameraPermissions = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (hasCameraPermissions != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
        int hasStoragePermissions = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasStoragePermissions != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
        if (hasCameraPermissions == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && hasStoragePermissions == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startCameraIntent();
        }
    } else {
        startCameraIntent();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.camera_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                quitAfter5();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.storage_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                quitAfter5();
            }
            break;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasCameraPermissions = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int hasStoragePermissions = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasCameraPermissions == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && hasStoragePermissions == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startCameraIntent();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT::
The change that caused this to crash was the fact that I had installed the custom kernel ElementalX on my Nexus 5 a few days earlier. I confirmed the issue just yesterday on my brother's Nexus 6 using the same kernel. I am going to shoot the kernel developer an email to see what he says about it.

As in the answer though, the code above really is the incorrect way to use the `requestPermissions` method anyway. So everyone just do it the right way and it will work for all devices :)

Comment: Um, why not just make one call to `requestPermissions()`? It takes an array of permission names, after all.

Comment: @CommonsWare So it does... I guess that will work then. It still doesn't explain why my code worked fine until today though.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you post that as an answer I will accept it. I found your permissions guide and have been following it now. 

Also, I discovered the reason my code fails now. It must be related to the custom kernel I recently installed on my device. I will have to shoot a bug report to them, though passing in a list really is how permissions should be checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best-case scenario that I would expect from two consecutive calls to `requestPermissions()` is for two consecutive-yet-separate dialogs to appear. I would not expect the behavior that you are seeing. I have done similar multiple-`requestPermissions()` calls, in the form of not handling configuration changes properly, and both editions of the dialog appeared.

All else being equal, you're better off just requesting all the permissions in `requestPermissions()`, so there is a single dialog. That will better fit user expectations, and I think that it would simplify your code a pinch.

Comment: I had some weird issues on Android Marshmallow when asking for two different permissions in two different calls at the same time on an app start (the program crashed a couple of times). Asking for both in one requestPermissions() seemed to fix that.